# How to declare inheritance of uicontrol objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, matlab-guide

I'm learning how to programmatically create an app in MATLAB with a graphical user interface. I'm using MATLAB 2015a.

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

```
Error using GuiTitle
The specified superclass 'uicontrol' contains a parse error, cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, or
is shadowed by another file with the same name.
```

I'm trying to make a class called GuiTitle that has uicontrol as the superclass. My class GuiTitle looks like this:

```
classdef GuiTitle < uicontrol
    methods
        function obj = GuiTitle(text)
            if nargin == 0
                text = '';
            end

            obj@uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'String', upper(text));
        end
    end   
end
```

Here is my code:

```
function hello_gui
% Test GUI

GuiConstants % contains constants that 
GuiTitle %%

f = figure('Visible','off','Position',[POS_FROM_LEFT,POS_FROM_BOTTOM,...
                                       WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT]);
set(f, 'MenuBar', 'none')

titleText    = 'process variable names';

%title = uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'String', upper(titleText));

title        = GuiTitle(titleText) %%

title.Position = [0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT];
title.FontSize = FONT_SIZE;

f.Visible = 'on';

end
```

When I comment out lines with %% and uncomment

```
title = uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'String', upper(titleText));
```

The window displays properly:

[image: correct output]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I’m not sure, but I think the UI classes are all Java classes, not MATLAB code, this might be the reason it doesn’t work.

Comment: I'll be building an app that requires a lot of windows to gather user input. Many of the windows will have similar layouts and GUI elements, so I'm just trying to learn how inheritance works at the moment.

Comment: Our current program requires user input to model a system, and the input process is incredibly tedious. In order to increase usability, we are making the input process a GUI.

Do you know why my question got downvoted?

Comment: I don't know why it got downvoted. I think it's a good question. In principle there is no need to derive from UI controls. Typically you'd create a control and set its callback functions. This is why I asked "why are you trying to do this?". Do note also that `uicontrol` is a function, not a class. It creates an object of class `UIControl`, but that is not a standard MATLAB class, there is no `classdef` file associated with it. I guess it's a Java object underneath. All of the GUI objects are opaque classes, you cannot do anything with them except through the functions defined to create them.

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo this was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`uicontrol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) is a function that creates an object of type `matlab.ui.control.UIControl`:

```matlab
h = uicontrol;
class(h)    % returns 'matlab.ui.control.UIControl'
```

However, this class is sealed and cannot be used as a superclass:

```matlab
classdef myclass < matlab.ui.control.UIControl
   ...
```

> ```
> >> a=myclass
> Error using myclass
> Class 'matlab.ui.control.UIControl' is Sealed and may not be used as a superclass.
> ```

Note that GUIs in MATLAB are designed very differently from what you might be used in other languages. There is no need to derive from UI classes to change their behavior, you define their behavior by setting callback functions:

```matlab
h = uicontrol;
h.String = 'button';
h.Callback = @(src,event) msgbox('pressed the button!');
```